# OpenTK circle rotation

Tags: graphics, rotation, opentk

I'm working on my first project using openTk. I'm creating virtual arcball for 3D model rotation. It works fine, but I need to add circle which won't rotate with model. This circle should visualize arcball.
My code to achieve rotation is:

```
private void SetCamera()
{
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
    Matrix4 scale = Matrix4.Scale(magnification / diameter);
    Matrix4 translation1 = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(-center);
    Matrix4 rotation = Matrix4.CreateFromAxisAngle(axisOfRotation, angleOfRotation*(float)numericSensitivity.Value);
    Matrix4 translation2 = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.5f);
    if (rotationChanged)
    {
        oldRotation *= rotation;
        rotationChanged = false;
    }
    modelview = translation1 * scale * oldRotation * translation2;
    GL.LoadMatrix(ref modelview);
}
```

So I would like to ask if there is some way how to draw circle, which wil be unaffected by this rotattion (will be on same position on a screen).

Comment: they way i've done it in the past...you just have to render all your 3D stuff using your regular projecton matrix, then swap it out for your "2d matrix" and render the rest of your UI

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then all you need to do is set the modelview matrix back to the identity before you draw your circle.  You can easily do that using the PushMatrix() and PopMatrix() functions.  Something like this:

```
//Draw normal things

GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
GL.PushMatrix();
GL.LoadIdentity();

//Draw un-rotated circle

GL.PopMatrix();
```

PushMatrix() saves the current matrix onto a stack, and PopMatrix() pops the top matrix off of that stack.  This means PopMatrix() will take you back to your normal rotated frame of reference after you're done with the circle.